# Erlang: Find intersections in a ets table

Tags: erlang, ets

I have an ets with the next items:

```
[at, {other_place}, me],
[other_place, {place}, {other_place}]],
[at, {place}, me], 
[on, {surface}, {object}],
[small, {object}]
```

And I have the list `[[at, door, me],[on, floor, chair],[small, bannanas]]`

I need to compare every item in the ets table to an item in the list and if the first one is the same atom, replace the items in round brackets. So if I have `[at, door, me]`, it matches with `[at, {other_place}, me]`, I have to change `{other_place}` for the atom door in all the ets table.

Comment: The data stored in ets tables are tuples where one index, often 1, is chosen as the key in all the data. I don't quite see you wish to map your data onto that. Is there a lot of data? If not, and if you don't wish to share data between processes, then you could look into using dicts or gb_trees instead. Some operations are easier on them.

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be accomplished with [ets:foldl](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/ets.html#foldl-3) by passing list to be compared to as an Acc argument.

If necessary list can also be folded with [lists:foldl](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html#foldl-3) if you need to go through it's sublists.